# Mythological character in the Hindu newspaper logo

Tags: identification-request

[image]

In the national newspaper the logo at top of newspaper **a character is depicted at left**. It was believed by some to be **Kamadhenu** from Hindu mythology. **But why those wings?**... so much like the [Ahura Mazda](https://thebawaguy.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/dsc_02661.jpg) of [Zoroastrian faith from Persia](https://thebawaguy.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/14/):

[image]

> Known as Gayomard, the sculpture reveals the body of a bull, the face of a human being and the wings of a supernatural being.

**Can  someone enlighten who is that he or she supposed to actually represent in *The Hindu* newspaper logo?**

EDIT1:

It is undeniable that the cow is held in highest veneration among the Hindus, but that is not the point here.

Wiki [reference](http://www.philamuseum.org/collections/permanent/88274.html) unedited to an extent reinforces the above:

> This vision of Kamadhenu, the wish-granting cow of ancient Hindu legend, combines a white zebu cow with the crowned, frontal female face, colorful “eagle” wings, and peacock tail of *Buraq*, the animal *(horse)*  that the prophet Muhammad rode to heaven on his night journey (Miraj). From at least the fifteenth century, *Persian paintings* showed Buraq with a horse’s body, *wings,* and a woman’s face; the peacock tail may have been an Indian addition. Popular portrayals of Kamadhenu in India today often show her *in this Indo-Persian composite form*; this may be one of the earliest images to merge the visual characteristics of the Hindu Kamadhenu with the Islamic Buraq.

So although wingless form is in the scriptures, this winged Avatar is not indigenous to Hindu India but is adapted, as Hinduism sanctions proper assimilation.. or so it appears to me even now.

EDIT2:

The winged creature can be also found in ( **Indonesian** Blog, page 3 Figure *1: 3 = Winged Winged Cow Man* ):

http://vokapb.blogspot.in/

Penemuan Modern.  Pada tahun 1843, Botta, konsul Perancis di Mossoul, menemukan istana raja Assyria di bawah sebuah bukit dekat Tigris. Di sini untuk pertama kalinya orang bisa melihat produksi seni Assyria; sapi bersayap yang dipahat di batu, yang ditempatkan di gerbang istana ditemukan utuh, dan dipindahkan ke Museum Louvre di Paris. Penggalian Botta menarik perhatian Eropa, sehingga banyak ekspedisi dikirimkan. Place dan Layard berhasil menemukan reruntuhan istana lainnya. Reruntuhan ini terjaga dengan baik, terlindungi oleh kekeringan iklim dan oleh lapisan bumi. Mereka menemukan dinding yang dihiasi dengan relief dan lukisan; patung dan prasasti ditemukan dalam jumlah yang besar.

Google Translation

Modern Discovery. In 1843, Botta, the French consul in Mossoul, discovered the king's palace of Assyria under a hill near the Tigris. Here for the first time one can see the art production of Assyria; The winged cow carved in stone, placed at the palace gate found intact, and transferred to the Louvre Museum in Paris. The excavation of Botta drew European attention, so many expeditions were sent. Place and Layard managed to find other palace ruins. These ruins are well preserved, protected by climate drought and by layers of the earth. They find walls decorated with reliefs and paintings; Statues and inscriptions are found in large numbers.

EDIT3:

[Gayomard Iranian Link](https://www.iranicaonline.org/articles/gayomard)

seems to have a mysterious Agni/ Sun ( word Marthanda) temple connection with ancient India.

Comment: It is clearly Kamadhenu but not sure whether Kamadhenu has wings or not.

Comment: Kamadhenu has no wiings.

Comment: See [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lHYKT.png).

Comment: Yes, it is also labelled/annotated.

Comment: However, the artist cannot imagine it himself and put it before millions of people for daily view without some credible and detailed description from the Puranas .

Comment: @Narasimham I wasn't sure why you had the link to Iran_King_in_India in your question so I removed it for clarity. If you want you can add it back.

Comment: The link depicts a carving of a huge sandstone winged animal so I included it   for visual impression and for what I think is more clarity. As a boy 12 years age my school-bus daily passed in front of  two Parsee Fire temples in Mumbai with such idols. So I was sort of convinced.

Comment: .... except they are sculptures of a winged bull but Kamedhenu is a winged cow.

Comment: @Narasimham I added the actual pic. in question for comparison. Now I understand why you linked that blog. Also, you linked to the blog's homepage so I was confused. Now I updated your question with the correct link which is [this one](https://thebawaguy.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/14/) - this has the correct pic. you were comparing it with.

Comment: There is an character itself on page 318 [Tarkshya][6]
  [6]: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=PwsYAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=dhara%20sacrifiA%20Classical%20Dictionary%20of%20Hindu%20Mythology%20and%20Religion,%20Geography,%20History%20...ce%20flow%20water&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK7ZCVpNvTAhWIr48KHbGmACoQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: There is an indian mythological character itself

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kamadhenu is also represented with wings. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamadhenu):

> Another representation of Kamadhenu shows her with the body of a white Zebu cow, crowned woman's head, colourful eagle wings and a peacock's tail. According to the Philadelphia Museum of Art, this form is influenced by the iconography of the Islamic [Buraq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buraq), who is portrayed with a horse's body, wings, and a woman's face. Contemporary poster art also portrays Kamadhenu in this form.

Image from [Philadelphia Museum of Art](http://www.philamuseum.org/collections/permanent/88274.html?mulR=7702)

[image: Kamadhenu with a calf]

Even Wikipedia profile image for Kamadhenu has wings :

[image: Kamadhenu sculpture at the Batu Caves, Malaysia]

<sub>Sculpture of Kamadhenu at the Batu Caves, Malaysia</sub>

It might not be the traditional way of representing Kamadhenu but it still belongs to her.

From [The Destroyer's comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15200/mythological-character-in-the-hindu-newspaper-logo#comment37354_15200) about full The Hindu logo meaning:

[image: Hindu newspaper logo from the question]

Comment: I think Kamadhenu at Shiva linga is also showing another mythological event.